# A list of suggested problems / problem set in Willard's Topology?

Tags: general-topology

I've been working independently through Willard's *General Topology* and have realized that if I ever wish to study something else, I should probably do fewer of the exercises. However, considering that I am learning the topic, I am less able to discern which exercises I should do.

Does anybody have a set of homework assigned from Willard, or another "suggested problems" list, that could help me curate my choices? My general approach has been doing the problems which seem like they relate to foundational ideas, and then doing one or two of the more challenging sets, but I seem to spend about as much time reading the problems to figure out what they say, as I do solving them!

Comment: I don't understand why you would read that book if you reading Topology first time. Anyway **Munkres Topology** contains very specific problem, and those are very useful to build concept.

Comment: Willard is a comprehensive text which I use mostly as a reference for difficult theorems.  If you can get through it, you will be a master in point set topology.  Often exercises are a continuation of the chapter instead of just pratice problems.  What chapter are you currently reading?   As I have a copy of Willard we could easily consider a selection of exercises together for a chapter or two.

Comment: @manmaid Willard was 20% the cost of Munkres, and I technically am not learning topology for the first time, but my first text had a lot of holes and poor motivation.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I am currently on the exercises in section 7, which is in chapter 3. I'd be much further had I not insisted on doing every exercise in sections 1-4...

Comment: @OpalE you may try ebooks, libgen may be... anyway, if you are not studying topology seriously, ignore my comment!

Comment: @OpalE.  I'd skip 7B, 7F, 7K, 7L.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind if I create a chat room where this could be discussed in the future, or is there some other better way? So we don't have an extended conversation in the comments.

Comment: @opal Email is much better.  marshh at comcast dot net